# -bash: cqlsh: command not found ERROR on running cql command outside cqlsh

Tags: cassandra, cql, cqlsh

I'm running the below command on Linux:

```
cqlsh -u cassandra -p cassandra -e "SELECT rule_name FROM cassandra.table1 ;"
```

It's giving this error:

```
-bash: cqlsh: command not found
```

Possible solutions?

**Note**: Cassandra version - **3.0.9**

Comment: just do `export PATH=$PATH:path_to_cassandra_install/bin`

Answer (score 1):

Yep, I get the same thing on my local:

```
~/local/apache-cassandra-3.11.6 » cqlsh 127.0.0.1 -u aploetz -p xxxxxxxx
zsh: command not found: cqlsh
```

Like Alex said, you can either path it or use explicitly location:

```
~/local/apache-cassandra-3.11.6 » bin/cqlsh 127.0.0.1 -u aploetz -p xxxxxxxx
Connected to AShowOfHands at 127.0.0.1:9042.
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.6 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]
Use HELP for help.
```